# JBL Go Bluetooth Ubuntu 18.10 not recognized

Tags: bluetooth

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.10 and unfortunately the device is not recognized. The Bluetooth is working properly, but doesn't  visualize the JBL go for pairing. Suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read https://askubuntu.com/tour and improve (https://askubuntu.com/posts/1112931/edit  ) your question. In a terminal window, `journalctl /usr/sbin/bluetoothd` will show you some logs.